# Why does randomising the order of measurements remove time as a confounding variable?

Tags: time-series, experiment-design, group-differences, confounding

Say we're interested in the difference in x between Group1 and Group2. We might measure 50 samples from Group1 then 50 samples from Group2. If the accuracy or precision of our measurements change over time, our design would introduce time as a confounding variable.

To remove the effect of time as a confounding variable, we should randomise the order in which measurements are taken of Group1 and Group2.

But I'm struggling to get a clear understanding of why randomising the order of measurements removes time as a confounding variable. Can anyone explain? Even better can anyone provide a visualisation of how randomising the order of measurements removes time as a confounding variable?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine (for example) that measurements were increasing over time.

Then if you measure Group1 before Group2, the difference in their means will include the effect of the difference in time.

So some clever person says ... "Okay, so let's do half Group 1, then do Group 2 and then do half Group1"... and that would work fine if the effect of time on the average measurement was *linear*.... but what if it increased and then decreased?

By randomizing times, you eliminate the biases that would be caused by the fact that you measure group values at different points in time when time itself impacts the outcome, even if it does it in ways you don't anticipate.